# multiple database connections and multiple windows forms in one project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm connecting a visual c# project to a database but i'm confused at the part when i have multiple forms do i need to call the databaseconnection class again in the design of both forms or just the main form?

Comment: Please add more details. (eg. example code)

Comment: simple answer would be "no, you just need to pass the connection object reference to all your forms", but you really should add more details